# Make a web app in Go?

Tags: html, web-applications, web, go

How can I make a web app in Go?

Is there a way I can interchangeably use Go code and HTML like with PHP and HTML?

More specifically, what I want to know is how to get my PrintLn output to show in a web browser and how to accept input from HTML form fields?

Comment: Writing a web app in Go: http://mwholt.blogspot.com/2013/05/writing-go-golang-web-app-with-nginx.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't embed Go & HTML (for many, many reasons) but you can use Go's html/template package (http://golang.org/pkg/html/template/) to generate a HTML page from your HTTP handlers.

I'd suggest reading http://golang.org/doc/articles/wiki/ and using http://www.gorillatoolkit.org/ (routes, cookies, etc) for the web server side

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup a web server in go and process http request/response as input/output. There is already an answer about go web frameworks which would be helpful. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12591445/what-web-framework-to-use-while-developing-in-go-language/12592579#12592579)

If you don't want your ui to show in a browser window, you will have to bind your own html engine. For that purpose you can look at ui frameworks like [walk](https://github.com/lxn/walk) which has ie based webview builtin or engine bindings like [go-webkit](https://github.com/mattn/go-webkit) which builds a custom webview.